# SMS Text Messaging Stopped Altogether

Tags: sms, twilio

We are using CIVICRM 5.463.

We have Twilio SMS set up and it did work great for a period of time but now has stopped working for individual and group texts.

The send outbound SMS cron job is completing successfully.

When you send the message, CIVICRM displays the message that the text was sent successfully.

Yet no texts are being received by anyone. The process ceased to work about 2 weeks ago.  No technology changes coincides with this timeframe.

Any ideas where I should look to figure out the issue?

Comment: What do twilio records show? Is it at least reaching twilio?

Comment: I have the same issue. The logs at Twilio do not show anything

Answer (score 2):

This is likely related to the A2P 10DLC requirement effective September 1, 2023. You can check the error log to confirm it is  [30034 error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30034) in Twilio at Monitor > Logs > Error Logs. If the texts are being delivered from CiviCRM to Twilio than it is a Twilio issue.

You can follow the [instructions here to registration your brand](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260800720410-What-is-A2P-10DLC-). This is to combat SMS spam. Essentially, SMS reputation rules are finally catching up with email.

FWIW, Twilio has made this *a lot easier* now that it effects all organizations as it can be done all in the UI and is well-documented than a couple years ago when it was a requirement for [political orgs and  special use cases](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402972441243-Special-Use-Cases-for-A2P-10DLC) and could only be done in CLI.